# Why is /etc/mysql/my.cnf EMPTY?

Tags: server, mysql

I am trying to edit the `my.cnf` file to allow remote access and ultimately using software from my Windows Server to configure scheduled backup for MySQL Server.

I was following [these instructions](https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2014/09/23/enable-remote-access-of-mysql-on-ubuntu/). 
However, the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file on my Ubuntu has only:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

It doesn't contain any configuration that I can edit. Why is it like that?

Comment: All it means is that the file is just in default state, in original form since installation

Comment: Your definition of EMPTY is a little bit strange.

Comment: It literally contains 0 configuration settings. It's not a zero-byte file, but it is completely free of any configuration other than directives that import the actual configuration files.

Answer (score 38):

Firstly, as A.B. rightly points out, the file is not empty. It has two rather important directives, namely

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Those lines are saying that **additional** configuration files (.cnf in this case) can be found in the directories listed:

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d/
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

The latter of the two directories should contain **mysqld.cnf**. In other words, the appropriate configuration file should be:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Comment: somethings not right either way. when I edit the halfway-empty my.conf file and e.g. set wait_timeout = 600, the service mysql cannot be started anymore..

Comment: This is exact answer for the question.

Comment: Wish I could find it 6 hours earlier!

Comment: @Blauhirn Same here when I state a password here. Without it the service starts but apparently under [mysqld] not everything gets parsed right like wait_timout and password.

Comment: You are a legend!

Answer (score 6):

The file isn't empty. It contains comments - the lines with a leading `#` -  and import statements -the lines with a leading `!`. An import statement means other configurations will be used, too.

Editing a configuration file also means adding new configuration lines.

Answer (score 5):

My file is the same. You need to add the correct group above the command you're trying to put in otherwise the service wont start.

To add `bind-address` you will need to add `[mysqld]` above it.

If you need to check what the groups are for the other commands, there's an example `my.cnf` file [here](http://mixeduperic.com/downloads/org-files/ubuntu/etcmysqlmycnf-ubuntu-12041-default-file.html).

If you want to enable remote connections [from all interfaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/139323/how-to-bind-mysql-server-to-more-than-one-ip-address) (i.e 0.0.0.0), your file would look something like below, however be sure you set up your firewall correctly if you do.

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]    
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Note the [mysqld] group.

Comment: This is such pain in a**. Have been trying to make remote connections work for almost two days now. Remote connections should be enabled out of the box.

Comment: Why would you expose every database server to the internet out of the box? Aren't there enough unsecured systems out there?

Comment: [If you wish to access it from more than one, but less than all the interfaces, you should bind to 0.0.0.0 and firewall off the interfaces you don't want to be accessed through.](https://serverfault.com/a/139326)

Answer (score 4):

In that case, that file is not the main where all the information about bind-adress, binlogs and etc include. But there is another file, where they include. Try this:

```
nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

It helped me, and It should help you.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16.04 / MySQL 5.7 at least `my.cnf` is actually empty because it's a symlink to another file which symlinks back to `mysql.cnf` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` mentioned in other answers. Make your changes here as mentioned above.