# mysql version 8.0.11 and Symfony 4 error "MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: mysql, php

I' m using Symfony 4 and Mysql version is 8.0.11 and using a user instead of a root login and when i try to use the command `php bin/console make:migration` i get this error:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 126:                                                                                 
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away                                                                                

In PDOConnection.php line 50:                                           
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away  

In PDOConnection.php line 46:                                                
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away  

In PDOConnection.php line 46: 
PDO::__construct(): Unexpected server respose while doing caching_sha2 auth: 109
```

Then i tried to search online and i found out that something went wrong with the MySQL variables `wait_timeout` and `max_allowed_packet` and had to change those variables on the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, the problem is when i go edit that file i only find this:

```
# Copyright (c) 2015, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2.0,
# as published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This program is also distributed with certain software (including
# but not limited to OpenSSL) that is licensed under separate terms,
# as designated in a particular file or component or in included license
# documentation.  The authors of MySQL hereby grant you an additional
# permission to link the program and your derivative works with the
# separately licensed software that they have included with MySQL.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License, version 2.0, for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301  USA
#
# The MySQL  Server configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

so then i tried to see a thread called "[Why is /etc/mysql/my.cnf EMPTY?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699903/why-is-etc-mysql-my-cnf-empty)" and a user said to use one of these paths:

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d/
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

and so i tried...
`/etc/mysql/conf.d/`:

```
## Copyright (c) 2015, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2.0,
# as published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This program is also distributed with certain software (including
# but not limited to OpenSSL) that is licensed under separate terms,
# as designated in a particular file or component or in included license
# documentation.  The authors of MySQL hereby grant you an additional
# permission to link the program and your derivative works with the
# separately licensed software that they have included with MySQL.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License, version 2.0, for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301  USA

#
# The MySQL  Client configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysql]
```

in the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`:

```
# Copyright (c) 2014, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2.0,
# as published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This program is also distributed with certain software (including
# but not limited to OpenSSL) that is licensed under separate terms,
# as designated in a particular file or component or in included license
# documentation.  The authors of MySQL hereby grant you an additional
# permission to link the program and your derivative works with the
# separately licensed software that they have included with MySQL.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License, version 2.0, for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301  USA

#
# The MySQL  Server configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

and in the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`:

```
# Copyright (c) 2014, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2.0,
# as published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This program is also distributed with certain software (including
# but not limited to OpenSSL) that is licensed under separate terms,
# as designated in a particular file or component or in included license
# documentation.  The authors of MySQL hereby grant you an additional
# permission to link the program and your derivative works with the
# separately licensed software that they have included with MySQL.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License, version 2.0, for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301  USA

#
# The MySQL  Server configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

and in any of these files i failed to find the MySQL variables `wait_timeout` and `max_allowed_packet`, so thanks in advance if someone could help me with this problem. :)

P.S:(i already runned this command `php bin/console make:migration` several times before this error and also created databases and went fine so its seems to not be an installation problem).

**Update:** it seems successfully changed the two variables `wait_timeout` and `max_allowed_packet` globally by adding to the three files the following

```
max_allowed_packet=1024M 
wait_timeout=3000000
```

and then using this command `sudo service mysql restart`
giving me this:

```
mysql> SHOW global VARIABLES LIKE "wait_timeout";
+---------------+---------+
| Variable_name | Value   |
+---------------+---------+
| wait_timeout  | 3000000 |
+---------------+---------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+------------+
| Variable_name      | Value      |
+--------------------+------------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |
+--------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

but still when i tried using this command `php bin/console make:migration` it gave me the same error has mentioned above this post, also tried to change the `wait_timeout` variable to 300 by the same method and it gave me the same result. :(

using this command `sudo vim /var/log/mysql/error.log` i get this:

```
2018-07-29T18:55:18.382164Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 8  user: 'alexandre'.
2018-07-29T18:55:20.288756Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2018-07-29T18:55:20.642118Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 31833
2018-07-29T18:55:21.704556Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-07-29T18:55:21.720385Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.11'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

**Update:**
I've desintalled mysql and php and changed to mysql 5.7 and php 7.2.7, the php change might have solve it acording to [link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76660&thanks=6)  the user @jibe, if someone can't still solve the problem i let these two other links
[link 1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html)
  and [link2](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/issues/299).