# Why is MySQLd not loading the cnf file?

Tags: mysql

I recently installed a test mysql server instance on Ubuntu 18.04 with MySQL 5.7.33. When the server starts, it's using defaults and not the proper cnf file.

```
root@host2:~# mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1 
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

/etc/my.cnf is a valid file and has proper perms.

I also tried this which google says will show the cnf loaded but there is none.

```
root@host2:~# ps aux | grep mysql
mysql      1010  0.4  5.2 1600976 207244 ?      Sl   10:19   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I'm at a loss of what to do next.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18 do you mean 18.04?

Comment: mysql is the client, mysqld is the daemon. What exactly is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in this post, at least the link to the config that was loading...
[Why is /etc/mysql/my.cnf EMPTY?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699903/why-is-etc-mysql-my-cnf-empty)