# Problem with phpmyadmin?

Tags: server, apache2, login, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem I can not log in to phpmyadmin constantly would throw out three errors

```
Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Although I know I set everything up right. I watched various tutorials but nothing worked and I need this urgently

Comment: This error is while fetching the url, or after entering the username/password credentials?

Comment: After entering the username and password

Comment: Run from terminal: `mysql --help | grep .cnf` to check where the mysql configuration file is located. Then open that file, and check the username/password section. Also check if you can login to mysql from terminal (`mysql` -user root -password aaaaa`)

Comment: When I typed the command miskl --help | grep .cnf I got the output order of the desired, mi.cnf, $ MISKL_TCP_PORT, /etc/mi.cnf /etc/miskl/mi.cnf ~ / .mi.cnf In the first location / etc / can't find my .cnf file and in another location / etc / miskl / of course it opens the file mi.cnf but it is the same as on the link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/699903/why-is-etc-mysql-my-cnf-empty) Can I now to type the command mysql -user root -password aaaaa`?

Comment: I'm sorry but I wrote the output of the mysql --help | command badly grep .cnf in the previous comment. Here's the way out
                       order of preference, my.cnf, $ MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~ / .my.cnf

Comment: Open  /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf and check for the password (if you are type correct).

Comment: The contents of the my.cnf file located at / etc / mysql are on the link https://postimg.cc/bGf17sQv

Comment: You are using ubuntu desktop or ubuntu server?

Comment: Ubuntu desktop 21.10

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting all packages related to apache server, phpmyadmin and mysql and then I adjusted everything from scratch with the help of this clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mUqaGe54nY&list=LL&index=7&ab_channel=AlejandroMV Anyway Chris P thank you for your help